# Trigger dropdown using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap dropdown and I want to trigger it with some other button.

```
<li class="dropdown">
      <a href = "" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" id = "TAdropdown" aria-expanded="false">Insert TA<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" >
          <div class="form-group" id = "TAform">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder = "Roll Number" required>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder = "M.A.C address" required>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onClick = "addMAC()" >+</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onClick = "removeMAC()" >-</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onClick = "submitForm()">Submit</button>
        </form>

      </ul>
    </li>
```

I want this to be triggered (open) when I click on this other button:

```
  <button type = "submit" class="btn btn-default" onClick = "deleteTA()">delete</button>
```

ie what should be I put inside the deleteTA() function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you need to toggle dropdown this way:

```
function deleteTA(e) {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown().dropdown('toggle');
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Where you pass event object into function:

```
<button type="submit" onClick="deleteTA(event)" class="btn btn-default">delete</button>
```

It's important here that you stop event propagation otherwise dropdown will immediately close.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/TfdnoGdW1CMpbZlHl62A?p=preview

Comment: A follow up question
I have two buttons to add and remove elements to the dropdown menu. The code for adding:
        `var form_element = document.getElementById("TAform");
 var input = document.createElement("input");
 input.type = "text";
 input.setAttribute("class", "form-control")
 input.placeholder = "M.A.C address";
 input.required = true;
 form_element.appendChild(input);`
As soon as I press this a new field adds but the dropdown Immediately closes.

Comment: You need to prevent event bubbling from your button click event: `e.stopPropagation()`.

Comment: @dfsp That was a strange problem. The dropdown was disappearing because the button type was "submit" which seems to refresh the page which would obviously close the dropdown. Changed it to type = "button". Works fine now. Anyway thanks!

Comment: I see. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

In the [bootstrap documentation on dropdown](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#dropdowns) (with interactive examples enabled) it is given in "Usage" section as:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
```

Hope that helps.